Issues with Dynamic Pagination in React Application with Ant Design and ASP.NET
I have a table that displays data with pagination using the Ant Design Table component. I'm trying to ensure that the pagination updates dynamically based on the number of filtered items. Additionally, I use moment.js for date manipulation and an ASP.NET API to fetch the data. Below is the relevant code snippet for how I'm handling pagination and data fetching:
const [pagination, setPagination] = useState<TablePaginationConfig>({
current: 1,
pageSize: 10,
});

This state hook initializes pagination with default values: current page set to 1 and pageSize set to 10.
const transformParamsForRequest = (params: any): RelatorioDeDevolucoesRequisicaoDto => {
const { changedPagination, sortField, sortOrder, StartDate, EndDate, ...rest } = params;

if (changedPagination) {
    setPagination(prev => ({
        ...prev,
        current: changedPagination.current,
        pageSize: changedPagination.pageSize,
    }));
}

return {
    ...form.getFieldsValue(),
    ...rest,
    StartDate: StartDate ? moment(StartDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') : undefined,
    EndDate: EndDate ? moment(EndDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') : undefined,
    PageSize: changedPagination?.pageSize || pagination.pageSize,
    CurrentPage: changedPagination?.current || pagination.current,
    SortField: sortField || sorting.sortField,
    SortOrder: sortOrder || sorting.sortOrder,
};
};

This function converts the parameters from the UI into a request format for the API. It updates the pagination state if changedPagination is provided and formats dates using moment.js. It also includes sorting and pagination parameters.
const fetchData = async (params: any): Promise<void> => {
setLoading(true);

const queryObject = transformParamsForRequest(params);

await SanegeoRelatoriosService.getRelatorioDeDevolucoesAsync(queryObject)
    .then(result => {
        setAllData(result.Items);
        setFilteredData(result.Items);
        setPagination(prev => ({
            current: queryObject.CurrentPage || 1,
            pageSize: queryObject.PageSize || 10,
            total: result.Total,
        }));
    })
    .catch(e => {
        if (e.Message) message.error(e.Message);
    })
    .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
    });
 };

This asynchronous function fetches data based on the transformed request parameters. It updates the state with the fetched data, sets the pagination state with the current page, page size, and total items, and handles loading and errors.
<Table
size="small"
tableLayout="fixed"
columns={columns}
rowKey="CodigoOcorrencia"
dataSource={filteredData}
pagination={pagination}
loading={loading}
onChange={(pagination, filters, sorter) => {
    const sortField = Array.isArray(sorter) ? (sorter[0]?.field || '') : (sorter?.field || '');
    const sortOrder = Array.isArray(sorter) ? (sorter[0]?.order || '') : (sorter?.order || '');

    fetchData({
        changedPagination: pagination,
        filters: filters,
        sortField: sortField,
        sortOrder: sortOrder,
    });
}}
bordered
style={{ marginTop: '16px' }}
/>

